# For Schwartz $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x,x)=0$, is the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{f(x,y)}{\lvert x-y \rvert^{n}}dxdy$ finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $f$ be a Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, I wonder if the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{f(x,y)}{\lvert x-y \rvert^{n}}dxdy
\end{equation}
is finite for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have tried to find a bound for the denominator $\lvert x-y \rvert^{n}$ but it is a bit tricky due to $x$ and $y$ being together. At least, I somehow guess that $f(x,y)$ converges to zero faster than any $\lvert x-y \rvert^{n}$ as $(x,y) \to (x,x)$.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If you put $f(x,y) = (g(x) - g(y)) h(x-y)$ where $h$ is a bump function supported on some ball around 0 then $f$ is Schwartz and it feels like you can make $f(x,y) \approx \nabla g(y) (y-x)$ and not an arbitrary power?

Comment: Why would it be finite?  For instance, $f$ could be $(x-y)^{n-1}$ in the unit disc.  Is this part of another problem?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hmm..then I am quite confused about what the answer is for [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466638/for-a-tempered-distribution-f-on-mathbbr2-what-exactly-does-it-mean-by).

Comment: @BrianMoehring Could you perhaps help me with [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466638/for-a-tempered-distribution-f-on-mathbbr2-what-exactly-does-it-mean-by)? The above ME post is in an attempt to understand the question in the link..

Comment: I can't see the article referenced there and have never studied this topic, but it sounds like you need to assume every derivative also vanishes on the diagonal: $(D^\alpha f)(x,x)=0$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^2$

Comment: @BrianMoehring If you assume like that, I guess the answer to this ME post is "yes"?

Comment: that may not be enough for the double integral. that assumption gets you $f(x,y) = f(x,x) + f_y(x,x)(x-y) + ... \partial^{n-1}_y f(x,x)(x-y)^{n-1}+ O((x-y)^n) = O((x-y)^n)$ which guarantees convergence of the inner integral wrt x or wrt y individually, for all $n$, but you can't continue for a second integral unless you're integrating on compact sets. In such a case I think you need to add some decay in the orthogonal direction $x+y$, so something like, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $D^\alpha f(x,y)(1+ |x+y|^2)^{1+\epsilon} \le C_n |x-y|^n$ for all $n$ and all $\alpha$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor According to your insight, I think a compactly supported smooth function $f$ with $D^\alpha f (x,x)=0$ for all $\alpha$ seems to qualify.